# Check if a color filter is applied on an image using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have the following images.

Color filter vs No filter

[image: 1]

The top image is the normal image, while the bottom image was applied a red filter on it. Is there any way to detect if a color filter was applied on an image using OpenCV?

I'm quite new to OpenCV, so I don't really know a lot about manipulating color with OpenCV.

Comment: you can compute the RGB histogram and detect if the R channel has "too many" high values

Comment: a *filter*? there is no way. this picture could have been taken like that. it's called "white balance". -- you can assess white balance. that will not give you a "yes/no" answer but the required information to adjust the image to look "balanced"

Comment: There is no bulletproof method, you could be picturing a poppy field. Follow Ivan's advice.

Comment: You can do it if you place a colour calibration chart in your photo when taking it. You can then photograph a second time without the card and apply the same correction.